# perl regular expression digit on string

Tags: regex, perl

I was trying to get the number from a string. The number can be pure digits e.g. `12334` or can be separated with underscore `12_345`

I was trying with the below code but was unable to get anything from it.

```
my $string = "this is a 141_153_923 number : $_123_456";          

if ($string =~ /\b\d*(?:\d+\_?\d+)*\d*\b/) {
    print "$&\n";
}
```

expected output is `141_153_923`

I have also tried with string `141_153_923` and it it still not returning anything even with

```
$string =~ /\b\d\b/
```

on the string `141_153_923`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have the variable `$_123_456` is declared in your `Perl` code. Otherwise you'll get an warning.

Now the regex. Try with this one:

```
if ($string =~ /\b(\d+(?:_\d+)*)\b/) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `/((?:\d+\_?)+)/`.

```
...
my $string = "this is a 141_153_923 number : \$_123_456";
my $num;
if  (($num) = $string =~ /((?:\d+\_?)+)/) {
  print "first: $num\n";
}

$string = "this is a 141153923 number : \$_123_456";
if  (($num) = $string =~ /((?:\d+\_?)+)/) {
  print "second: $num\n";
}
...
```

output:

```
first: 141_153_923
second: 141153923
```